# Can one add additional metadata to drive files (excluding the description field)?

Tags: google-drive-api

I believe its a must for drive files to be able to carry application specific metadata (ie extended attributes). As files get passed around we need to be able to track them outside drive.

Is there such capabilities?

If not, will there be? timeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now supported with [Custom file properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/properties).. The eta (~Apr 5, 2013) was about 268 days from the question. However, the properties are not searchable, nor is there a datatype defined... Clock started, again.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible, but it is a feature we are considering.  I don't have an ETA for the feature at this time.  In the interim, as you say, you can use the description field for this purpose.  Another way to do this is to set properties in the indexableText of a file, and the search for those properties using the `q` parameter of the Drive API.

Comment: Was this feature ever implemented/scrapped?